# Do we need both the [career] and [employment] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We seem to have two tags [career](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and [employment](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment) about career advice in TCS. Currently, career has 21 questions, and employment has 3 questions where each one has also been tagged as career.

Do we need both tags? Can we eliminate the employment tag?

Comment: Feel free to merge.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela I wasn't sure how to merge, so I went to the 3 questions and just removed the employment tag. Hopefully that is equivalent.

Comment: I think one way to do this "correctly" is to suggest "employment" as a synonym of "career". There is a system that lets people to suggest synonyms and others to support the suggestions, but I am not sure how actively people use it, though (requires some amount of reputation). The easiest solution might be to let the moderators take care of it?

Comment: I can merge them when this post gets another upvote (total +4).